# Missing code after git merge. Commit is present, but does not show in the file changes. How can we get out changes back?

Tags: git, visual-studio

We have quite a problem with missing code after a mess-up with a merge.

What (we think) happened: We had a change on our develop branch that needed to be put into the release.
While merging, we did not want to take all commits, but only our specific files.

We used visual studio to do a merge from develop to release and unchecked the 'Commit changes after merging' option. We got a long list of 3000+ files that were changed, of which we staged and committed our 10 files and undid all the others. When we then pushed, it looks like not only our new commit went through, but also all the other commits where we undid the files. Periodically, the release branch is merged into development when a bugfix has happened.

We now noticed that certain files lost their changes. If we check the commit's history, it shows that file 'A' should be changed, but if we check file 'A''s history, the commit does not show.

It looks like we've lost months of work. How can we get our missing changes back into our branch?

Comment: I can't address any questions about how Visual Studio *displays* things, but at the level of Git itself, every commit has a full snapshot of every file. This is true of merge commits as well. What makes a merge commit special—making it a merge, instead of just an ordinary commit—is that it refers back to *two* predecessor commits, instead of just one. Comparing the snapshot in the merge to one predecessor will show you what's different in those two commits. Comparing the snapshot in the merge to the other predecessor will show you what's different in those commits.

Comment: You must literally look at two separate comparisons, to *really* see what happened. This is hard to view (and not useful when it's overwhelming), so many viewers don't "like to" show you this much stuff, so they just don't show it. This makes viewing what happened "through" a merge hard.

Comment: In any case, there is no such thing as "a file's history". The history in the repository is the commits in the repository: nothing more, nothing less. When you use `git log --follow <filename>`, Git has to fake up a file history, by discarding most of the commits from the display. (They still exist, you just don't *see* them.) The choice of which commits to display, and which not to, makes it *look* like you've lost stuff. Nothing is lost! It's all there, in commits. You just don't like the commits that you have now, after the merge.

Comment: In general, the solution to this is to *repeat the merge*. The merge did not change anything: it just added a new commit. The old commits still exist, with their old content. You can do the merge over again and this time, *avoid* "undoing" parts of the merge.

Comment: but the merge does not show any changes to the files in question.

Comment: As I said, many viewers just don't *show* you "changes" with a merge. They can't. There aren't any changes with *any* commit, including merges. But viewers *can* show changes with non-merge commits, by *comparing the snapshot in the previous commit* to the snapshot in the merge. Whatever is different in these two, that's what "changed". Try that with a merge, though: which previous commit will you use? The first previous commit? The second previous commit? Both? Neither? Which choice does *your* viewer use?

Comment: when I use `git diff` locally (Windows 10, command line) between the merge and the previous commit, it only returns the changes that weren't undone. I can't seem to find a way to show where our change in file 'A' went back to the original state.

Comment: The merge has two previous commits. Which previous commit are you comparing? The changes that are missing are from one "side" of the merge, presumably. If you compare against that side of the merge, you'll see things being *un*-done. If you compare against the side of the merge that *doesn't* have those changes, you won't see anything, because that side of the merge doesn't have those changes.

Comment: Remember, a merge has a *full snapshot of every file*. That snapshot is the *correct result of the merge*. If, from base to side A, user A changed file A, and from base to side B, user B changed file B, the merge *commit* should have a change to file B as compared to side A, and a change to file A as compared to side B. That's the combined set of changes. But if someone says "we don't want the B changes" and makes the merge snapshot contain only what's in side A, well, that's the *correct result*, because that's how merges are defined.

Comment: I recommend spending a day or two learning about how git actually works (spoiler: each commit is a full snapshot of your entire project and a branch is just a pointer to a commit). Then you can easily find the desired commit with `git-log` or `rev-list` and recover your data.

Comment: I 'think' I have pinpointed the missing commits, but there are 265 commits missing. How can I best restore those?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `reflog` Command of git: [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

We had a similar problem and i was able to get back the content of changes that got lost in a merge.

A good entry point is the documentation of [atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog)

Comment: The commits still exist and show the changed files, so we do still have the changes. We just don't know which commits were impacted and if we have that list, how to get those changes back on our develop branch.